# Why is notifyDataSetChanged() working like that?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have the following situation:

In my `MatchActivity` there is a method called `executeBustConsequences()` which is updating attributes that are included in lists that are the base of my custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` `MatchRecyclerViewAdapter`.

After updating the values `executeBustConsequences()` looks like that:

```
        updateAverages(playerDarts, playerPoints, playerAverage);
        // reset boolean, update match view and go to next player
        resetMultiplier();
        getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        nextPlayer();
```

Right before `getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()` is executed, `getCurrentDart() == 2` and `getPlayerIndex() == 0`.

Inside the adapter then I see the following attribute values:
`getCurrentDart() == 1` and `getPlayerIndex() == 1`.

At first I didn't understand why that happened, but now I think I do.

This is the method `nextPlayer()`:

```
    private void nextPlayer() {
        if (getPlayerIndex() == getMatchParticipants().size()-1) {
            setPlayerIndex(0);
        } else {
            setPlayerIndex(getPlayerIndex() + 1);
        }
        setCurrentDart(1);
    }
```

To me it looks like `nextPlayer()` was executed before `notifyDataSetChanged()` even though `nextPlayer()` should be executed after `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Can anybody explain to me why that is the case? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Use a debugger to navigate through the execution of your code to see by yourself the order of calls and what is called by what. It's the easiest way to understand what's going on

Comment: I debugged it several times already. The only issue is that when ```notfiyDataSetChanged()``` is executing, it jumps into android libary code. At this point I use "Run to Cursor" to jump back into my adapter code. But I'm not sure what happens inbetween. Is there any way to jump over code that I didnt write myself?